# How much overhead is there when creating a thread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

I just reviewed some really terrible code - code that sends messages on a serial port by creating a new thread to package and assemble the message in a new thread for every single message sent. Yes, for every message a pthread is created, bits are properly set up, then the thread terminates. I haven't a clue why anyone would do such a thing, but it raises the question - how much overhead is there when actually creating a thread?

Comment: A single worker thread will help with some of the other kinds of resource contention that you might have with a multiple threads (interleaved writes etc).

Comment: I would like to comment that yes, this is arguably a horrible thing to do - which leads to my question, how much overhead is incurred when creating a thread (in general)

Frankly, I do not know how to determine or even measure an implementation of the pthread library

Comment: The overhead is **0.37%**, given the right message size.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt Can you explain how you came to that number?

Comment: @Dai: Yes. For an infinitely long message, the overhead will be 0%, for an empty message it will be 100%. So for some message size in between (the "right" message size) it will be approximately 0.37%.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt I'm sorry, but I can't tell if you're being facetious or not.

Comment: @Dai: Yes, I am joking, sort of: The original question is lacking crucial information. Without information about the transfer rate of the serial port and the length of the messages, a proper answer cannot be given.

Comment: I’m shocked that a question I asked 13 years ago is suddenly getting traction. Since this was something I worked on so long (and 4 or 5 jobs ago), my recollection is vague…. But I believe the intent of my question was really to try to understand what overhead there might be by spinning up a new thread for every message to be sent along a serial port. (Which still seems odd to me all these years later), and would be independent of baud rate of the actual serial send.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> > ...sends Messages on a serial port ... for every message a pthread is created, bits are properly set up, then the thread terminates. ...how much overhead is there when actually creating a thread?

This is highly system specific.  For example, last time I used VMS threading was nightmarishly slow (been years, but from memory one thread could create something like 10 more per second (and if you kept that up for a few seconds without threads exiting you'd core)), whereas on Linux you can probably create thousands.  If you want to know exactly, benchmark it on your system.  But, it's not much use just knowing that without knowing more about the messages: whether they average 5 bytes or 100k, whether they're sent contiguously or the line idles in between, and what the latency requirements for the app are are all as relevant to the appropriateness of the code's thread use as any absolute measurement of thread creation overhead.  And performance may not have needed to be the dominant design consideration.

Answer (score 84):

To resurrect this old thread, I just did some simple test code:

```
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  for (volatile int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    std::thread([](){}).detach();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread -O3 -o test`. I then ran it three times in a row on an old (kernel 2.6.18) heavily loaded (doing a database rebuild) slow laptop (Intel core i5-2540M). Results from three consecutive runs: 5.647s, 5.515s, and 5.561s. So we're looking at a tad over 10 microseconds per thread on this machine, probably much less on yours.

That's not much overhead at all, given that serial ports max out at around 1 bit per 10 microseconds. Now, of course there's various additional thread losses one can get involving passed/captured arguments (although function calls themselves can impose some), cache slowdowns between cores (if multiple threads on different cores are battling over the same memory at the same time), etc. But in general I highly doubt the use case you presented will adversely impact performance at all (and could provide benefits, depending), despite having you already preemptively labeled the concept "really terrible code" without even knowing how much time it takes to launch a thread.

Whether it's a good idea or not depends a lot on the details of your situation. What else is the calling thread responsible for? What precisely is involved in preparing and writing out the packets? How frequently are they written out (with what sort of distribution? uniform, clustered, etc...?) and what's their structure like? How many cores does the system have? Etc. Depending on the details, the optimal solution could be anywhere from "no threads at all" to "shared thread pool" to "thread for each packet".

Note that thread pools aren't magic and can in some cases be a slowdown versus unique threads, since one of the biggest slowdowns with threads is synchronizing cached memory used by multiple threads at the same time, and thread pools by their very nature of having to look for and process updates from a different thread have to do this. So either your primary thread or child processing thread can get stuck having to wait if the processor isn't sure whether the other process has altered a section of memory. By contrast, in an ideal situation, a unique processing thread for a given task only has to share memory with its calling task once (when it's launched) and then they never interfere with each other again.

Comment: Tangent: ran across this thread, as a Windows user I was curious how my system fared. Compiling under msvc with standard release optimisations, running on a 6700k it took 31.442s to run fully. The only alterations I made were to add a std::chrono::high_resolution_clock + time_points before and after the loop and std::cout the result before exiting. Rather shocking results. I tried mingw-w64's 7.1.0 g++ with your your exact command line arguments but it crashes after a few seconds so no idea what's wrong there, same with a clang++ v8.0 I had lying around.

Answer (score 20):

I have always been told that thread creation is cheap, especially when compared to the alternative of creating a process.  If the program you are talking about does not have a lot of operations that need to run concurrently then threading might not be necessary, and judging by what you wrote this might well be the case.  Some literature to back me up:

[http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/OpSystems/Myos/threads.htm](http://www.personal.kent.edu/%7Ermuhamma/OpSystems/Myos/threads.htm)

> Threads are cheap in the sense that
>
> 1. They only need a stack and storage for registers **therefore, threads are cheap to create.**
> 2. Threads use very little resources of an operating system in
>    which they are working. That is,
>    threads do not need new address space,
>    global data, program code or operating
>    system resources.
> 3. Context switching are fast when working with threads. The reason is
>    that we only have to save and/or
>    restore PC, SP and registers.

More of the same [here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/research/thmon/thmon2a.html).

In [Operating System Concepts 8th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470279931) (page 155) the authors write about the benefits of threading:

> **Allocating memory and resources for process creation is costly.**  Because
> threads share the resource of the
> process to which they belong, it is
> more economical to create and
> context-switch threads.  Empirically
> gauging the difference in overhead can
> be difficult, but in general it is
> much more time consuming to create and
> manage processes than threads.  In
> Solaris, for example, creating a
> process is about thirty times slower
> than is creating a thread, and context
> switching is about five times slower.

Comment: But the alternative is probably a single reused thread, or a thread pool, not a process.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen I meant the alternative to creating any thread, not an alternative to creating a thread(s) in the way the question describes :)

Comment: Actually process creation is cheaper than thread creation. The fork part of processes creation has basically no cost as the memory pages are duplicated at the hardware level. See what the google chrome team found: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MicrosoftIE8AndGoogleChromeProcessesAreTheNewThreads.aspx

Comment: @Martin York according to my text books (and my professors) process creation is more costly than thread creation.  I will add an excerpt from one of my text books so you can judge for yourself.

Comment: @ typoknig: It was true in the old days. I am not saying it is free but it is a myth that it is very expensive. See the article I linked in my last comment.

Comment: @Martin York the article seems to say that process creation is faster than it once was because of `"this thing called Moore's Law that keeps marching on"`, but that does not compare process to threads on an level playing field.  If process creation has gotten faster by an order of magnitude then thread creation would also have gotten faster.  In my understanding, there is no way creating a process can ever be done faster than creating a thread because a process will always have more stuff in it than a thread.

Comment: Yes you quotes are from text books that are OLD. In the old days a fork() required the OS to generate a copy of each memory page that the processes was using. Modern versions of the kernel have moved fork implementation into the protected realm and now use a copy on write technique (that basically means only one page (that page with the current stack frame) needs to be copied at the fork() point). See: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jms/cw-fork.pdf

Comment: @typoknig: The problem with thread creation it involves a lot of work setting up a new stack on the other hand processes creation noways is very cheap as the pages used by the processes are copied only when needed thus your forked process in-effect are sharing the same memory pages. Please read the first article a little more closely.

Comment: The advantage of threads: Quicker to switch, data is easily shared. The advantage of fork: processes protection (if the process dies it does nto affect the other processes).

Comment: @Martin York The link you provided is not dated, but its newest reference is 1990. My book is in its 8th edition and was copyrighted in 2009. The original version of my book was published in 1985 which is still newer than most of the references in the link you provided. The link you provided does not compare processes and threads, in fact it does not even mention threads. I would totally agree with your most recent comment, but I still think (based on what I have been taught and what my references say) process creation will always be more expensive than thread creation.

Comment: @typoknig: Try it and see. It is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: @Martin York I actually have, and that is the only reason I would even try to stand my ground talking about this with you since you obviously know your stuff with such a big number next to your name :)  I am in Advanced Operating Systems right now and most of the semester has been spent on POSIX threads. My professor had an example program which timed the creation of a thread vs. the creation of a process. Process creation always took considerably longer. The program was written in C and run in RedHat, I will see if I can get it from him.

Comment: Id did not know RedHAt was still around :-) . What version of the Kernel are they using?

Comment: Are you comparing fork/exec against thread creation? This is definitively more costly than thread creation (because of the exec). But is not equivalent. You just want to compare the fork time against thread creation as you can write the child code in the same application (just like a thread). Here are my two versions: fork vs pthread_create. http://padfly.com/threadVsfork Admittedly I have nothing for the child to do but I create 1000 children in either and it takes 0 time (or its so fast that time XXX records zero).

Comment: [Alpha:~/X] myork% ./thread 1000
Start: 717836
Wait:  352700
All:   1070536

Comment: [Alpha:~/X] myork% ./fork 1000
Start: 22628
Wait:  1439
All:   24067

Comment: The above times were generate using the code posted here http://padfly.com/threadVsfork Running on Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0. Each version generates 1000 children (which do nothing and then exit). Though I would not rely on the absolute values of a clock() as a timing mechanism I think this shows that the cost of fork() is actually smaller. Now I will concede that different OS will have different characteristics based. Windows for example will not fair as well but Unix like OS running a modern kernel will behave in this manner. Older Kernels that do not use copy on write will also be slower

Comment: @typoking: This is getting to heavy for a thread discussion. I have started a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934992/fair-comparison-of-fork-vs-thread

Comment: @ubiquibacon : did you you ever ear of fork bomb attacks using threads ?

Answer (score 14):

There is some overhead in thread creation, but comparing it with usually slow baud rates of the serial port (19200 bits/sec being the most common), it just doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree. Why worry about microseconds of delay from creating a thread when networking is likely cause delays in the dozens of milliseconds or even seconds.

Answer (score 12):

You definitely do not want to do this. Create a single thread or a pool of threads and just signal when messages are available. Upon receiving the signal, the thread can perform any necessary message processing.

In terms of overhead, thread creation/destruction, especially on Windows, is fairly expensive. Somewhere on the order of tens of microseconds, to be specific. It should, for the most part, only be done at the start/end of an app, with the possible exception of dynamically resized thread pools.

Comment: Yes, an "eternal" dedicated worker thread would also solve the possible MT problems.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn : have you got an idea on how to do this [in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33453581/2284570) ?

Answer (score 9):

I used the above "terrible" design in a VOIP app I made.  It worked very well ... absolutely no latency or missed/dropped packets for locally connected computers.  Each time a data packet arrived in, a thread was created and handed that data to process it to the output devices.  Of course the packets were large so it caused no bottleneck.  Meanwhile the main thread could loop back to wait and receive another incoming packet.

I have tried other designs where the threads I need are created in advance but this creates it's own problems.  First you need to design your code properly for threads to retrieve the incoming packets and process them in a deterministic fashion.  If you use multiple (pre-allocated) threads it's possible that the packets may be processed 'out of order'.  If you use a single (pre-allocated) thread to loop and pick up the incoming packets, there is a chance that thread might encounter a problem and terminate leaving no threads to process any data.

Creating a thread to process each incoming data packet works very cleanly, especially on multi-core systems and where incoming packets are large.  Also to answer your question more directly, the alternative to thread creation is to create a run-time process that manages the pre-allocated threads.  Being able to synchronize data hand-off and processing as well as detecting errors may add just as much, if not more overhead as just simply creating a new thread.  It all depends on your design and requirements.

Comment: This makes no sense. If a thread crashes your whole app is going down, unless on your OS it's catchable, in which case you can take that opportunity to spawn a new thread. If it's not an outright crash, but an exception/error-code, the thread can catch it and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 8):

Thread creation and computing in a thread is pretty expensive: all data structures need to be set up, the thread registered with the kernel and a thread switch must occur so that the new thread actually gets executed (in an unspecified and unpredictable time). Executing `thread.start` does not mean that the thread main function is called immediately.

As the article (mentioned by typoking) points out creation of a thread is cheap only compared to the creation of a process. Overall, it is pretty expensive.

I would never use a thread

- for a short computation
- a computation where I need the result in my flow of code (that
  means, I am starting the thread and
  wait for it to return the result of
  it's computation

In your example, it would make sense (as has already been pointed out) to create a thread that handles all of the serial communication and is eternal.

Comment: The downvotes are baffling. Understanding the cost of context switches is core to any discussion of threading costs.

Comment: Your second bullet seems to rule out async here - although I guess that's because async is C++11 and your answer was written in '10.

Answer (score 6):

For comparison , take a look of OSX: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)

- Kernel data structures : Approximately 1 KB Stack space: 512 KB
  (secondary threads) : 8 MB (OS X main thread) , 1 MB (iOS main
  thread)
- Creation time: Approximately 90 microseconds

The posix thread creation also should be around this (not a far away figure) I guess.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed very system dependent, I tested @Nafnlaus code:

```
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  for (volatile int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    std::thread([](){}).detach();
  return 0;
}
```

On my Desktop Ryzen 5 2600:

windows 10, compiled with MSVC 2019 release adding std::chrono calls around it to time it. Idle (only Firefox with 217 tabs):

It took around 20 seconds (20.274, 19.910, 20.608) (also ~20 seconds with Firefox closed)

Ubuntu 18.04 compiled with:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread -O3 -o thread
```

timed with:

```
time ./thread
```

It took around 5 seconds (5.595, 5.230, 5.297)

The same code on my raspberry pi 3B compiled with:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread -O3 -o thread
```

timed with:

```
time ./thread
```

took around 15 seconds (16.225, 14.689, 16.235)

Answer (score 3):

On any sane implementation, the cost of thread creation should be proportional to the number of system calls it involves, and on the same order of magnitude as familiar system calls like `open` and `read`. Some casual measurements on my system showed `pthread_create` taking about twice as much time as `open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)`, which is very expensive relative to pure computation but very cheap relative to any IO or other operations which would involve switching between user and kernel space.

Comment: In my case, this would involve creating thousands of threads. Is there a way to [avoid that in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33453581/2284570) ?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting.

I tested with my FreeBSD PCs and got the following results:

```
FreeBSD 12-STABLE, Core i3-8100T, 8GB RAM: 9.523sec<br/>
FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE, Core i5-6600K, 16GB: 8.045sec
```

You need to do

```
sysctl kern.threads.max_threads_per_proc=500100
```

though.

Core i3-8100T is pretty slow but the results are not very different. Rather the CPU clocks seem to be more relevant: i3-8100T 3.1GHz vs i5-6600k 3.50GHz.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this seems to be very OS dependent.  On my Core i5-8350U running Win10, it took 118 seconds which indicates an overhead of around 237 uS per thread (I suspect that the virus scanner and all the other rubbish IT installed is really slowing it down too).  Dual core Xeon E5-2667 v4 running Windows Server 2016 took 41.4 seconds (82 uS per thread), but it's also running a lot of IT garbage in the background including the virus scanner.  I think a better approach is to implement a queue with a thread that continuously processes whatever is in the queue to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying the thread everytime.