# What kind of overhead to c++11 threads introduce?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Coming from C# / Java programming, creating new threads in programs tends to add a significant amount of overhead (for example 1MB per thread in C#). I was curious what kind of overhead do C++11 threads introduce.

Comment: Virtual memory is not normally considered a scarce resource.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Under 32 bit it is. In fact, long-running processes can (and do) die from address space starvation when their dynamic memory becomes fragmented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ offers a fairly thin wrapper on top of the underlying implementation, leading to no significant additional overhead. In fact, you can even [get a handle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) to the underlying OS thread, which will be a [`__gthread_t`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/ext_concurrency_impl.html#manual.ext.concurrency.impl.thread), which is a pthread handle for g++ and a WINAPI thread handle for [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870808.aspx).

However, threads do have intrinsic overhead, because they need to be scheduled by the OS, contain a stack and so forth.

[An analysis by Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx) goes through the limits of thread creation under Windows. These limits are of course caused by the thread overhead and give:

- A thread requires about 1 MB of virtual address space (default linker setting)
- 4-16 KB of initial commit size
- 12-48 KB of nonpageable memory

Comment: Also, it should be noted that the thin wrapper of std::thread looks alot like boost::thread, which for some machines is just a wrapper of pthreads.

Comment: @It'sPete In fact, std::thread is such a thin wrapper for pthreads that for both gcc and clang add -lpthread is required for using it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Already solved here:

[How much overhead is there when creating a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929774/how-much-overhead-is-there-when-creating-a-thread)

Cliff Notes: this will be system dependent and the best way to know is to benchmark on your target system.