# Asynchronous method call in Python without creating threads or forking process?

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, cygwin, sendasynchronousrequest

Some years ago, *(for comparison)* synchronous JavaScript ajax requests were deprecated because of the overhead.
I’m in the following situation :

```
def ssh_network_operation_with_paramiko(string):
    server_response=Do_some_stuff_with_null_characters_in_string(string)
    Do_something_with_server_response(server_response)

for i in very_very_large_range
    ssh_network_operation_with_paramiko(i)
```

Basically, using process or threads would be synonym of creating a fork bomb.

So is it possible to do perform asynchronous calls  without creating threads or process like with ajax in JavaScript ? Because all I found currently involve creating threads or process were each of them perform only one function at time.

Comment: Use some kind of thread pool?

Comment: @Drakosha : In a python multiprocessing pool, each process perform one function at time *(implying waiting for server response)*, which is too slow.

Comment: not sure what you are looking for. In any case thread can do only one thing at a time. You might be looking for asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Drakosha yes, but with paramiko?