# Quick check to see if structure of function pointers is NULL in C99

Tags: c, structure, function-pointers, c99

In C99 is there an easier way of check if a structure of function pointers is NULL, other than checking each individual pointer?

What I currently have is similar to the following:

```
typedef struct {
    void* (*foo)(int a);
    int   (*bar)(int a, int b);
} funcs;

void *funcs_dll;

funcs_dll = dlopen("my_funcs_dll.so", RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (funcs_dll == NULL) {
    THROW_ERROR;
}

funs.foo = dlsym(funcs_dll, "foo");
funcs.bar = dlsym(funcs_dll, "bar");

if (!funcs.foo || !funcs.bar) {
    THROW_ERROR;
}
```

What I am looking to do is reduce the second if check, so that I do not need to check each individual function. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2589876/2703418).

Comment: Although the code is not formally well-defined behavior, [this example answers the question to 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll/23763255#23763255).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no.

You can't use `memcmp()` to compare to some constant buffer, since there might be padding inside the structure which will have "random" values. If you can make sure that the size of the structure is *exactly* the sum of the function pointer fields, you can perhaps go that way.

You can also use a proxy, by i.e. declaring an initial `uint32_t` member that is a bitset representing which function pointer(s) are valid. Then you can check up to 32 (or 64 with `uint64_t`) proxy bits in parallel.

If you only want to do this *once*, my suggestion would be a data-driven approach. Define a table of function names to look for, and process that in a loop, exiting as soon as a `dlsym()` call fails.

Something like:

```
const struct {
  const char *name;
  size_t     offset;
} functions[] = {
{ "foo", offsetof(funcs, foo) },
{ "bar", offsetof(funcs, bar) },
};
```

Data-driven code like this is very powerful, and often very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Make wrapper function for `dlsym` which will set error flag, if return value is NULL.