# C OR large block of memory without loop

Tags: c, null

I have a function which looks something like this `void doSomething(unsigned char buff[50]);` 
What I would like to do in my function is quickly determine if the buff is all nulls.

To do that I was thinking I could just bitwise **or** the buffer and check if the result is zero, since any **on** byte would cause the result of a bitwise **or** to be to be 1. A result of zero would indicate that all bytes in the array are zero.

Is there an easy way to do this in C without looping over the entire buffer?
It would be nice if it were cross platform.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're proposing - how would you "bitwise or" the buffer without looping over it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster approach to checking for an all-zero buffer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493936/faster-approach-to-checking-for-an-all-zero-buffer-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can reduce the number of iterations by casting to a 32- or 64-bit type before doing the checking. Just make sure to handle the extra 16 bits at the end properly.

Answer (score 1):

Not portable, but on x86 you can use the [REP SCAS{B,W,D} instructions](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/scasd.htm) to do this on x86.

Answer (score 0):

I think that part of the answer depends also on the length of your buffer.

If your buffer is 50 bytes long (that is, if it is pretty short and its length is known at compile time), yes, a bitwise OR (and casting, as Ignacio said in another answer) seems the right solution.

Otherwise, I'd code the loop in the old fashioned way (i.e., testing if each byte is zero) and let the compiler optimizations unroll the loop for me.